# TeamCity AssemblyInfo Patcher: How to use version with three digits?

Tags: teamcity

I'm using TeamCity's built-in AssemblyInfo version patcher to patch the Assemblyversion of my project.

This is the content of my AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2020.8.1")]
```

This is my AssemblyInfo patcher feature setting:
[image: AssemblyInfo patcher feature setting]

However, the actual version of my application is 2020.8.1.0 - it has four version digits and has a trailing zero:

[image: Actual version]

After researching a lot about this and reading several SO questions, I did not find a way to use a version with only three digits. The only way I can think of is using not the AssemblyVersion patcher, but a "general" patcher that can replace anything by using a RegEx. But before doing that, I prefer to update the AssemblyInfo version manually in my source code.

Is there a way to use the AssemblyInfo patcher with a three-digit version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Actually the trailing zero has nothing to do with TeamCity's AssemblyVersion patcher. It is simply the behavior of the AssemblyVersionAttribute itself. If you use a version with three digits, it will automatically set the revision number to "0". This is documented in the example code in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?view=netcore-3.1).